# Performance diff between two view adding approach

Tags: android, view, android-inflate, android-viewgroup, viewstub

What will be the diff in terms of performance of adding views dynamically ( using add/remove view methods of ViewGroup ) or putting them into a static layout xml file and let it be compiled into a binary form and inflated at runtime ( regular way ) ?

I know ViewStub is an option but I wonder if there's a difference of not inflating at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding views programatically is faster. When adding views from layout XML, it adds them in the same way but in addition, it needs to walk through that XML and use a lot of reflexion.

But it takes more developer afford :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I thought the same, but I only suspected if adding and converting view from a compiled binary form of layout might compensate the view tree walk. With adding programmatically, you also have the overhead of creating views ( allocation etc ) and extra function calls to add them into a layout properly. All in all,  I believe the diff is so insignificant that we may ignore it perhaps ?

Comment: Yes you are right, the change in performance is very minor. As the dynamic view creation takes less space, still I suggest to go with xml. Because code structure is also a very crucial part of programming. And the xmls are beauty of Android, it separates the view(need no logic) from your logic part. You no need to worry about multiple screens while creating a layout using xml. And it also takes a less afford to make changes in your screen. So better to go with xml layout, and try to create minimum views in java. Hope you are satisfied, let me know if you have any more queries :)